# Python: How to set the default value when the parameter type is function?

Tags: python

I am modifying a function which already have some parameters with default values.

I need to take in a function as a parameter, and it should have a default value which should be something like `None`, so that I can avoid using it when it is not set.

Below is a simple example, while actually `None` should not be used.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable

def myfunc(x: int=0, metric_func: Callable=None):
    '''Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "function"'''
    ret = []
    if metric_func == None:
        return ret

    for i in range(10):
        ret.append(metric(x, i))
    return ret

def dot(x, y):
    return x * y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunc(1, dot)
```

Comment: `lambda arg0, arg1: 1`?

Comment: Do you really want to return an empty list when `metric_func` isn't provided? That seems strange. (Also look at `typing.Optional`.)

Comment: Having `None` is actually ok, just add proper type hint like `Optional[Callable]` or `Callable | None`

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for reminding that, but it's just a simple example so that's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking into the standard library, you're using the most common method.

For instance in `heapq`[(1)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53455a319f3f2e5609fca2a313ea356fba318665/Lib/heapq.py#L316-L332) [(2)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53455a319f3f2e5609fca2a313ea356fba318665/Lib/heapq.py#L463) [(3)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53455a319f3f2e5609fca2a313ea356fba318665/Lib/heapq.py#L523), `bisect` [(1)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53455a319f3f2e5609fca2a313ea356fba318665/Lib/bisect.py#L4) [(2)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53455a319f3f2e5609fca2a313ea356fba318665/Lib/bisect.py#L19), `itertools` [(1)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53455a319f3f2e5609fca2a313ea356fba318665/Lib/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py#L4):

```py
def merge(*iterables, key=None, reverse=False):
    '''Merge multiple sorted inputs into a single sorted output.

    Similar to sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables)) but returns a generator,
    does not pull the data into memory all at once, and assumes that each of
    the input streams is already sorted (smallest to largest).

    >>> list(merge([1,3,5,7], [0,2,4,8], [5,10,15,20], [], [25]))
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20, 25]

    If *key* is not None, applies a key function to each element to determine
    its sort order.

    >>> list(merge(['dog', 'horse'], ['cat', 'fish', 'kangaroo'], key=len))
    ['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'horse', 'kangaroo']

    '''

    # skipping some lines

    if key is None:
        ...

    # skipping the rest
```

If you want to type it explicitly, just create a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) with `Union[Callable, None]` or `Callable | None` if using python >= 3.10.

You should check against `None` with `v is None` not `v == None`.

If possible, type your [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) otherwise it defaults to `Callable[..., Any]`.

And finally also if possible type your return value(s) where I've put `<idk>` markers.

```py
def myfunc(x: int = 0, metric_func: Callable[[int, int], <idk>] | None = None) -> list[<idk>]:
    '''Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "function"'''
    ret = []
    if metric_func is None:
        return ret

    for i in range(10):
        ret.append(metric_func(x, i))
    return ret
```